# Paypal express checkout causes a redirection to Failure action even when payment was succeeded, in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-express

when using Paypal Express Checkout, after authenticating in Paypal sandbox, browser is redirected to "/paypal/express/review/" that shows a page to confirm order... then I press a button called "Place Order" and the order is placed because Paypal funds are decreased by the order amount. Then browser is redirected to /checkout/onepage/success/ from Paypal, but immediately is redirected to /checkout/onepage/failure.

When I see the successAction of OnePageController, I saw this:

```
public function successAction()
{
    $session = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout();
    if (!$session->getLastSuccessQuoteId()) {
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
    }

    $lastQuoteId = $session->getLastQuoteId();
    $lastOrderId = $session->getLastOrderId();
    $lastRecurringProfiles = $session->getLastRecurringProfileIds();
    if (!$lastQuoteId || (!$lastOrderId && empty($lastRecurringProfiles))) {
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
    }

    $session->clear();
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
    Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_onepage_controller_success_action', array('order_ids' => array($lastOrderId)));
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

There is no a redirect to Failure action.

On the other hand, order is kept in "Payment Review" state and the invoice in "Pending" state.

Finally, I tell you that I have developed an observer that is called on "sales_order_invoice_pay" event. This event is called, even when the invoice remains in pending state.

What may this be causing this failure? when should orderbecome in "Complete" state?

Regards
Jaime

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to disable your custom observer and check once for make sure this error because of your customisation ?
If that is bcoz of your custom observer then please debug your code and fix this and let me know if any help needed for that.

Comment: Yes... that problem occured also before adding the observer... I cannot debug the code.. the only way I think I can is by placing some log messages in the successAction, but this problem comes from Paypal Express extension.

Comment: it is strange, but I have placed some log messages in /checkout/onepage/success/ and in /checkout/onepage/failure/ , and even when I see, using Development Tools, the URL /checkout/onepage/success/  being called, immediately I see a 302 HTTP response and calls /checkout/onepage/failure/. And also, I only see log messages from failure action.